# I need to make a code showing a winner of coin toss game, how to fix this?

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and started learning recently. I am writing a coin toss game, where I need to give 5 outputs, and whichever number (1,2) is printed thrice, will win the game. I cannot understand how to show the output of any single winner. this is the code I have written

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnJ1d.png)

Comment: Please do not post code as images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0):

So you already have a loop and you are picking either {1, 2} and printing it....

You need to:

1. (kinda obvious but...)  Clearly state in comment or at least in your head, what '1' and '2' stand for heads/tails
2. Introduce another variable, maybe even 2 variables... to count the number of heads/tails achieved.  (You can do it with one by deduction within 5 games, but if it is easier to get working, just make 2 variables....they're free after all.  :)  ).  Make these OUTSIDE of your loop so they don't get re-initialized in the loop.
3. Make the necessary *conditional* statements ("if statements") that will increase (update) the variables created above based on the outcomes within the loop.
4. Make additional *conditional* statements to figure out if your game-ending criteria has been meet.